# How to use Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

I've built multiple DNN and conVNN using tensorflow, and I can reach now a good accuracy. Now my question is how can I use this trained networks in  real example.
I case of a convNN for computer vision, how can I use the model to classify a new picture ? can I generate something like convNN.exe that get images as input parameter that through the classification result out ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you've trained the model, you should save it somewhere by adding code similar to

```
builder = saved_model_builder.SavedModelBuilder(export_path)
builder.add_meta_graph_and_variables(
      sess, [tag_constants.SERVING],
      signature_def_map={
           'predict_images':
               prediction_signature,
           signature_constants.DEFAULT_SERVING_SIGNATURE_DEF_KEY:
               classification_signature,
      },
      legacy_init_op=legacy_init_op)
builder.save()
```

Then, you can use [Tensorflow serving](https://tensorflow.github.io/serving/serving_basic) to serve your model using a high-performance C++ server by running

```
bazel-bin/tensorflow_serving/model_servers/tensorflow_model_server \
    --port=9000 --model_name=mnist \
    --model_base_path=/tmp/mnist_model/
```

Modifying the code for your model, of course. You'll need to implement a client; there's an example for MNIST [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/serving/blob/master/tensorflow_serving/example/mnist_client.py). The guts of the client would be something like:

```
def do_inference(hostport, work_dir, concurrency, num_tests):
  """Tests PredictionService with concurrent requests.
  Args:
    hostport: Host:port address of the PredictionService.
    work_dir: The full path of working directory for test data set.
    concurrency: Maximum number of concurrent requests.
    num_tests: Number of test images to use.
  Returns:
    The classification error rate.
  Raises:
    IOError: An error occurred processing test data set.
  """
  test_data_set = mnist_input_data.read_data_sets(work_dir).test
  host, port = hostport.split(':')
  channel = implementations.insecure_channel(host, int(port))
  stub = prediction_service_pb2.beta_create_PredictionService_stub(channel)
  result_counter = _ResultCounter(num_tests, concurrency)
  for _ in range(num_tests):
    request = predict_pb2.PredictRequest()
    request.model_spec.name = 'mnist'
    request.model_spec.signature_name = 'predict_images'
    image, label = test_data_set.next_batch(1)
    request.inputs['images'].CopyFrom(
        tf.contrib.util.make_tensor_proto(image[0], shape=[1, image[0].size]))
    result_counter.throttle()
    result_future = stub.Predict.future(request, 5.0)  # 5 seconds
    result_future.add_done_callback(
        _create_rpc_callback(label[0], result_counter))
  return result_counter.get_error_rate()


def main(_):
  if FLAGS.num_tests > 10000:
    print('num_tests should not be greater than 10k')
    return
  if not FLAGS.server:
    print('please specify server host:port')
    return
  error_rate = do_inference(FLAGS.server, FLAGS.work_dir,
                            FLAGS.concurrency, FLAGS.num_tests)
  print('\nInference error rate: %s%%' % (error_rate * 100))

if __name__ == '__main__':
  tf.app.run()
```

This is in Python, of course, but there's no reason you couldn't use another language (e.g. Go or C++) if you wanted to create a binary executable.